# Why is code 1 working properly, while code 2 isn't ? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying this excercise on Codebat:

Given a number n, return True if n is in the range 1..10, inclusive. Unless outside_mode is True, in which case return True if the number is less or equal to 1, or greater or equal to 10.

Code 1 :

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
  if not outside_mode:
      return  n in range(1,11)
  return n <= 1 or n >= 10
```

Code 2:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
  if outside_mode and  n <= 1 and n >= 10:
    return True
  elif n >= 1 and n <= 10:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Can somebody explain this to me, because i  think these codes are quite similiar.

Comment: I don't believe in just giving away the answer to a puzzle, but the following line is wrong: `if outside_mode and  n <= 1 and n >= 10`

Comment: Woops, , i really need to be more  specific in reading the excercises. Luckily i wasn't too far off. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong :

```
if outside_mode and  n <= 1 and n >= 10:
```

it is not possible that n is at the same time lower(or equal) 1 and greater(or equal) 10
it should be:

```
def in1to10(n, outside_mode):
  if outside_mode and  n <= 1 or n >= 10:
    return True
  elif n >= 1 and n <= 10:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```